# .env file created by Github action aren't being uploaded to aws S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, github-actions, aws-code-deploy

I want to upload the react + express project to S3, and deploy it to EC2 instance via Codedeploy, but I'm getting CodeDeploy AccessDeniedException errors even though EC2, Codedeploy, and IAM user all have permissions. I restarted Codedeploy and it is active now. 
I noticed that there is no .env file in S3 zip file uploaded by Github action, but the runnig log on Github action says it created an server/.env & client/.env file. 
I can't deploy using git clone in SSH ubuntu bc it won't work without the env. file. There may be another reason, but I'm assuming it's because the .env file wasn't passed to S3.

my folder structure(also assuming that the structure has problem. I have to move to /server for app starting. Needed .env file is in /client & /server folder, not Root folder.)

```
myApp
 -server
 -client
 -appspec.yml
 -scripts
```

main.yml for Github action

```
name: deploy

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.12.0]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
      - name: Checkout source code.
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: create server env file
        working-directory: ./server
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo PORT=${{ secrets.PORT }} >> .env
          echo MONGODB_URI=${{ secrets.MONGODB_URI }} >> .env
          echo SECRET_KEY=${{secrets.SECRET_KEY}} >> .env
          cat .env
        env:
          PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
          MONGODB_URI: ${{ secrets.MONGODB_URI }}
          SECRET_KEY: ${{secrets.SECRET_KEY}}
          
      - name: create client env file
        working-directory: ./client
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo REACT_APP_NAME_REGEX=${{secrets.REACT_APP_NAME_REGEX}} >> .env
          echo REACT_APP_PASSWORD_REGEX=${{secrets.REACT_APP_PASSWORD_REGEX}} >> .env
          echo REACT_APP_DEPLOY_URL=${{secrets.REACT_APP_DEPLOY_URL}} >> .env
          cat .env
        env:
          REACT_APP_NAME_REGEX: ${{secrets.REACT_APP_NAME_REGEX}}
          REACT_APP_PASSWORD_REGEX: ${{secrets.REACT_APP_PASSWORD_REGEX}}
          REACT_APP_DEPLOY_URL: ${{secrets.REACT_APP_DEPLOY_URL}}
          

      - name: build client files
        working-directory: ./client
        run: |
          npm install -g yarn
          yarn install
          yarn build
      - name: zip distributions
        run: zip -r myapp.zip ./client/build ./server ./appspec.yml ./scripts

      - name: AWS configure credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1-node16
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
        env:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}

      - name: upload to S3
        run: aws s3 cp ./myapp.zip s3://myapp/archive/

      - name: deploy with AWS codeDeploy
        run: aws deploy create-deployment
          --application-name myapp
          --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime
          --deployment-group-name deploy-group
          --ignore-application-stop-failures
          --s3-location bucket=myapp,bundleType=zip,key=archive/myapp.zip
          --description "Ignore ApplicationStop failures due to broken script"
```

appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu/build
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE

permissions:
  - object: /home/ubuntu
    pattern: "**"
    owner: ubuntu
    group: ubuntu

hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/before_install.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu

  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/after_install.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu

  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/application_start.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
```

before_install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy -y
sudo apt-get install npm  -y
sudo npm install pm2 -g
```

after_install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
REPOSITORY=/home/ubuntu/build/server
cd $REPOSITORY

sudo rm -rf node_modules
sudo npm install
sudo pm2 kill
```

application_start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

REPOSITORY=/home/ubuntu/build/server
cd $REPOSITORY
pm2 stop all
pm2 start app.js
```

codeDeploy log

```
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:37:in `block in start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:36:in `fork'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:36:in `start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/../lib/codedeploy-agent.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.11.0/lib/gli/command_support.rb:126:in `execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.11.0/lib/gli/app_support.rb:284:in `block in call_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.11.0/lib/gli/app_support.rb:297:in `call_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.11.0/lib/gli/app_support.rb:79:in `run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/../lib/codedeploy-agent.rb:90:in `<main>'
2023-04-21T08:16:52 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(684)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Cannot reach InstanceService: Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Errors::AccessDeniedException - Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Errors::AccessDeniedException
```

Comment: You don't zip it.

Comment: @CodeCaster Excuse me but I didn't understand...Are you saying I shouldn't upload zip files to S3 or that I didn't zip .env files together?

Comment: Your .env is in `./client/.env`, but you zip `./client/build`. Does yarn copy the .env file into the build directory? Is the .env file present in your zip?

Comment: @CodeCaster Oh, I Understood...I specified the wrong path. but why is there no .env file in /server either? They both show up as added files in github action log but aren't present in my zip.

Comment: You are specifying `working-directory` at each step. When you zip files, your `working-directory` is `./client`, does `server` also reside inside the `client` directory? You need to verify the current path with `pwd` and the contents with `ls -l` commands. Also, you should list the files of the zip file after creating it and `before_install.sh` script should be verifying all the files before proceeding. Apart from that, `env` is redundant if you use directly use `${{}}` syntax. After setting variables with `env`, directly use them e.g. `$VAR`. Otherwise, you can simply remove `env` sections.

Comment: According to your directory structure, you should be creating zip file while being at the root i.e. inside `myApp`. You need to adjust your workflow accordingly.

Comment: Is your last deploy step working fine? Looks like it's a single command where trailing slash `\\` is missing. Please add its logs in your question too.